# How can I query some APIs request that has same field as this one?

Tags: javascript, api, cypress

API request example: https://www.sbsb.com/api/v250/animals/123456789/humans/987654321 /transplant?$skip=0&$top=666&$orderby=animalAssociatedHumans/sortDate

Is there something like api/*/animals/*/humans/*/transplant?....../sortDate that will catch all similar APIs requests that have 'api', 'animals', 'humans', 'transplant' words in it ?

I am using it in cy.route('Get or Post', (url request: something I need), 'fixture:file')

Answer (score 1):

To catch all those words, allow the provided numbers between them, and allow any amount of stuff after `transplant` this should work:

```
cy.route("GET", "/api/*/animals/*/humans/*/transplant/**").as("getStuff")
```